# How to stop AnimationDrawable from repeating with a recomposition

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I am using accompanist-drawablepainter to display a AnimationDrawable within my composable.
I set the XML of the Drawable to OneShot, but my drawable starts to animate again if the screen gets recomposed - for example while after screen rotation or if I scroll away and then back to the image.
The drawable doesn't react to .stop() at all, isRunning always shows false.

I tried to put a .stop() after the Image composable.
I tried to display a static image for the next composition - for this I created a bool to check if it should animate or not.
The problem is, isRunning always shows false for the drawable.
What is the correct way to handle a animation drawable that should only show once, until there is a interaction (e.g. button pressed) or until the drawable gets changed?

Is there a better way to show a frame by frame animation within compose? Vectors unfortunately don't work for this animation.

Here is my current code:

```
@Composable
fun MainUnitCard(viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()){

    val homeUiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(LocalContext.current, homeUiState.mainUnitDrawableId) as AnimationDrawable

    Card(
        onClick = {
            viewModel.updateMainUnitConnected(!homeUiState.mainUnitConnected)
        })
    {
        Column {

            Image(painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = drawable, contentDescription = "")          
        }

    }
}
```

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
private val _onDrawable = R.drawable.anim_on
private val _offDrawable = R.drawable.anim_off

data class HomeScreenState(
    val mainUnitConnected: Boolean = false,
    val mainUnitDrawableId: Int = _offDrawable,
)

class HomeViewModel: ViewModel(){
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(HomeScreenState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<HomeScreenState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun updateMainUnitConnected(connected: Boolean){
        _uiState.update {
            it.copy(
                mainUnitConnected = connected
            )
        }
        updateMainUnitDrawable(connected)
    }

    private fun updateMainUnitDrawable(connected: Boolean){
        _uiState.update {
            it.copy(
                mainUnitDrawableId = if(connected) _onDrawable else _offDrawable
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried something like this:

```
@Composable
fun MainUnitCard(viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()){

    val homeUiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(LocalContext.current, homeUiState.mainUnitDrawableId) as AnimationDrawable
    var animState = false

    Card(
        onClick = {
            viewModel.updateMainUnitConnected(!homeUiState.mainUnitConnected)
            animState = true
        })
    {
        Column {

            Image(painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = if(animState) drawable else drawable.getFrame(39), contentDescription = "")          
        }

    }
}
```

However the bool obviously never survives and so there no longer will be a animation.
I also can't remember that variable, because I have no way to actually check if the animation is over or still running, at least that I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution for my specific problem..
In the end it was pretty simple.

I changed the ViewModel to AndroidViewModel and could use the application context to load my AnimationDrawable in the ViewModel now:

```
private val _onDrawable = R.drawable.anim_on
private val _offDrawable = R.drawable.anim_off

data class HomeScreenState(
    val mainUnitConnected: Boolean = false
)

class HomeViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(HomeScreenState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<HomeScreenState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()
    private var mainUnitDrawable = mutableStateOf(application.getDrawable(_offDrawable) as AnimationDrawable)


    private fun updateMainUnitDrawable(connected: Boolean){
        mainUnitDrawable.value = if(connected) getApplication<Application>().getDrawable(_onDrawable) as AnimationDrawable else getApplication<Application>().getDrawable(_offDrawable) as AnimationDrawable
        mainUnitDrawable.value.start()
    }

    fun getMainUnitDrawable(): AnimationDrawable{
       return mainUnitDrawable.value
    }

    fun updateMainUnitConnected(connected: Boolean){
        _uiState.update {
            it.copy(
                mainUnitConnected = connected
            )
        }
        updateMainUnitDrawable(connected)
    }

    fun getMainUnitConnected(): Boolean{
        return _uiState.value.mainUnitConnected
    }
}
```

and the composable:

```
@Composable
fun MainUnitCard(viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()){


    val homeUiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    Card(
        onClick =
        {
            viewModel.updateMainUnitConnected(!homeUiState.mainUnitConnected)
        })
    {
        Column {

            Image(painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = 
                            if(viewModel.getMainUnitDrawable().isRunning) viewModel.getMainUnitDrawable() 
                            else viewModel.getMainUnitDrawable().getFrame(39)),
                    contentDescription = "")
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:
The animation-drawable is set to OneShot in the XML and 39 is the last frame of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remember either on the bool or possibly for the animation itself. From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state):

> A value computed by remember is stored in the Composition during initial composition, and the stored value is returned during recomposition.

Example:

```
var animState = remember { false }
```

This will not be reinitialized on recomposition.

Comment: I tried remember { false }, but couldn't get it to work because I didn't find a way to reliable tell if the animation is over.
However, remember for the drawable actually is a really good idea and I didn't even think about that. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Great did that work? Please upvote if helpful!

Comment: Unfortunately no, the animation keeps restarting with every recomposition. I am still trying things out. I'll post my solution if I every find one.